# Intel Fortran expression returns incorrect result

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have a code as following:

```
program th
  implicit none

  integer N1
  integer maxi,ei,Nc,ns,na
  real CH1,CH2



  OPEN(unit=1,file='input_file',status="old")
  read(1,*) ns                      !!!
  read(1,*) ei                         !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
  read(1,*) maxi!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!    
  read(1,*) N1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  
  close(unit=1)


  CH1 = 0.07
  CH2 = -0.35


  Na = INT(abs(2.*((N1/2)*CH1 + (N1/2)*CH2)))
  write(*,*) Na,abs(2.*((real(N1)/2.)*CH1 + (real(N1)/2.)*CH2));stop
end program  th
```

and the input file is

```
1                      !!!!!!!!!!!
1                          !!!!!!!!!! 
1                   !!!   
1600
```

Then I compile it with

```
ifort -O3 -autodouble t1.f90 -o out
```

but when I execute it I get 447 for `na` which is not correct. The correct answer is 448.

Comment: Yes, that should be 448. What happens if you removed the INT( )?  It is an Integer anyway.  How about if you compile it without the -autodouble?

Comment: The problem is I need autodouble in the rest of the code

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying remove it permanently, but just try it for this bit of code on it's own.  It may be some sort of binary imprecision bug.  Trying those things might help narrow it down.

Comment: I did that, without autodouble works correctly, do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Some numbers can't be represented exactly in binary (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary), this can cause binary imprecision bugs.   Try 1) breaking your Na calculation into smaller part e.g. (N1/2)*CH1 on its own etc.   or possibly better 2) change it to N1*CH1/2.0 do multiplication before division and the same for the other part, change it to N1*CH2/2.0

Comment: the actual "correct" answer according to my hp is 448. Not going to get into an edit war over it though. In any case `NINT` will probably give what you expect.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with ifort 16.  With or without your flags, ifort 16 gives Na = 448.

Comment: ifort14 precisely reproduces the behavior of the Question. I believe this is not a bug, because the argument of INT() becomes like 447.99999999999994316... (in other cases, the argument becomes 448.0000.... so the difference is only within floating-point roundoff). So anyway, as @agentp suggests, NINT() is recommended if the answer is known a priori to be integers.

Comment: @Ross Yes I figured though that was unintentional mistake as the rest of your edit I thought was good.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be understood by investigating the numbers upto their full precision.

The number `0.07` is `7.0000000298023224E-02` in single precision and `7.0000000000000007E-02` in double precision. The number `800` can be represented exactly in both models.

However, the product of these numbers is approximately `56.000000238418579` and `56.000000000000006`, respectively. Due to the available precision, the first gets rounded towards `56` (in single precision) and the second towards `56.000000000000007` (in double precision).

As a result, the calculation in single precision "gains" some precision by rounding in the "right" direction.

Concerning the different behaviour of `ifort 16` mentioned by @casey, I guess there are some differences in rearranging the equation or maybe use of excess-precision for intermediate results. Though, this is only a guess.

Comment: When I remove input _file and put variable in the code, I get 448 correct value. Could you please tell why this happens?

Comment: I don't know. The assembler output (`-S`) should help us here, but I don't have a clue. I guess, that there are some optimizations during compilation which precalculate some results with different precision. Actually, there is now a difference between `(N1/2)*CH1 + (N1/2)*CH2` and `(N1/2)*(CH1+CH2)`.